# Unable to translate long HTML file in JS

Tags: javascript, html, angular-translate

```html
<span class="bold"> NOVA INTERACTIVE, S.A,</span> sociedad mercantil, debidamente registrada en la República de Panamá, que en lo sucesivo y a los efectos del presente documento se denominara: <span class="bold">”La Empresa”</span>, desarrolladora y propietaria del portal web denominado <span class="bold">“Clasifika.com”</span>, el cual, en lo sucesivo y a los efectos del presente documento se denominara: <span class="bold">“El Sitio”</span> , adquiere y así lo reconoce, por medio del presente documento, la plena responsabilidad de mantener todas las precauciones razonables dentro del ámbito tecnológico y legal,  para asegurar la privacidad y seguridad de los datos personales obtenidos, y recopilados por medio de <span class="bold">“El Sitio”</span> a  cualquier persona, natural o jurídica que manifieste la voluntad de hacer uso de los servicios ofrecidos por <span class="bold">“El Sitio”</span>, quien en lo sucesivo y a los efectos del presente contrato se denominara <span class="bold">“El Usuario”</span>. Dichos datos podrán incluir: nombre, apellido, correo electrónico, teléfono, domicilio, dirección, y cualquier otro dato o información que <span class="bold">“La Empresa”</span>, considere como necesarios y pertinentes para el correcto y eficaz funcionamiento de los componentes, servicios y/o aplicaciones integradas y/o relacionadas o asociadas a <span class="bold">“El Sitio”</span>. Asimismo, <span class="bold">“El Usuario”</span> declara conocer y aceptar que los datos antes mencionados, sean tratados conforme a los términos y condiciones del presente aviso de privacidad por parte de <span class="bold">“La Empresa”</span>.
```

I want to add translations for the above code.
I have maintained 2 files en.json (this contains English word translations) and another one es.json (this contains Spanish word translations)
Now for example, if I have to add translation for "Submit" word I just add following piece of code in my HTML file:

```
{{ 'SUBMIT' | translate }}
```

And I will include following changes in 2 files:

1. In en.json I will have: "SUBMIT" : "Submit"
2. In es.json I will
   have:
   "SUBMIT: "Enviar"

Same thing I want to implement for the above HTML piece of code.
But I am unable to do so.
Can anyone help me in it?

Answer (score 0):

For solving the issue:
I have added div container before code begins

```
<div ng-if="lang == 'es'">
```

The above one is for the Spanish translation.
For English one I have added

```
<div ng-if="lang == 'es'">
```

It worked for me!